# Unable to connect to Azure Cosmos DB using the MongoDB Driver .Net C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We cannot connect to Cosmos DB using the MongoDB driver when we deploy our application to a test server.

All our Dev machines have no issue but we are getting the following from test.
I get thats its an issue with a cert on the Machine but how do we fix it ?

```
 [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : 
"Unspecified/xxxxxxxxx.documents.azure.com:10255" }",
 EndPoint: "Unspecified/xxxxxxxx.documents.azure.com:10255", State: 
 "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: 
 "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: 
An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> 
 System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 
 The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

is the issue here the client cert being invalid ?

We have connections to Azure SQL instances without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, you could use [SslSettings.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_SslSettings_ServerCertificateValidationCallback.htm) for getting more details about the server certificate validation and check the policy errors to narrow this issue. You could construct your `MongoClientSettings` as follows for building your `MongoClient`:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl("{connection-string-of-your-cosmosdb}"));
settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings()
{
    EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
    ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        foreach (var element in chain.ChainElements)
        {
            // Gets the error status of the current X.509 certificate in a chain.
            foreach (var status in element.ChainElementStatus)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"certificate subject: {element.Certificate.Subject},ChainStatus: {status.StatusInformation}");
            }
        }
        return true; //just for dev, it would bypass certificate errors
    }
};
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
```